# Unable to render Configuration page of Mageplaza SMTP extension. Page is rendering as blank page

Tags: magento2.3, mageplaza

I have installed **Mageplaza SMTP** extension in my Magento site (v 2.3.1). The problem I am facing is that I am unable to see its configuration page when I try to access it from **`Stores >> Configuration >> Mageplaza >> Smtp`**

The problem does not happen only with the SMTP extension. I have tried **Google Recaptcha** of Mageplaza and it is showing me the same issue.

Instead of showing the configuration page in the backend it's showing a blank page.

Comment: Did you install mageplaza/core module?

Comment: @MSA Yes, I have installed mageplaza/core. I used composer to install mageplaza extensions.

Comment: In which mode you are working, I mean is it developer mode?

Comment: @SameerBhayani my site is in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

I raised a ticket regarding this issue with Mageplaza and they found out that there was a issue in my global configuration due to which configuration page was not rendering properly.

Mageplaza team's support is great and I will update this answer once my issue is fixed.